# Web dynamic project - different project name & deploy folder

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, Web dynamic project,

There is no issue , if project and deploy name is same name. but there is issue in ,if we wish to give different deploy name.

For example here is my .settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.component.

```
<project-modules id="moduleCoreId" project-version="1.5.0">
<wb-module deploy-name="sample">
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/" source-path="/WebContent"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes" source-path="/src"/>
    <wb-resource deploy-path="/WEB-INF/classes/" source-path="/ImportedClasses"/>
    <property name="context-root" value="sample1"/>
    <property name="java-output-path" value="/sample/build/classes"/>
</wb-module>
```

Above config i changed my deployment folder name as "sample1" and project name as "sample".

Comment: What eaxctly is the "issue"?

Comment: can't deploy project name with different deploy name/folder